# Stash - needs page refresh to reset

Tags: stash

I am new to the stash plugin so i am probably doing something wrong.

At the top of a layout template, i have a channel entry loop that sets a stash variable like so:

```
    {exp:stash:set
    save="yes" 
    scope="user" 
    parse_tags="yes"
    replace="yes" 
    refresh="60"
    output="no"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="subscribers"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
        dynamic="off"
        limit="1"
        author_id="CURRENT_USER"
    }
        {subscriber_children search:child_active="=YES" limit="1"}
            {stash:child_name}{child_name}{/stash:child_name}
            {stash:year_group}{year_group}{/stash:year_group}
        {/subscriber_children}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

In the page, there is a dropdown that allows the user to change the active_child, so on /page1 the user can select child2 to set to active, this jumps to /switch-child/entry_id where it sets the child to active, then redirects back to /page1. What i am seeing is that i have to manually refresh /page1 again to update the stash variable (child_name)

```
{exp:stash:get name="child_name"}
```

How do i get it to update when /page1 loads?

Comment: I've narrowed this down to parse order. I am trying to make the values child_name and year_group accessible across various template partials hence the need to query it once and stash it.

Comment: Try adding process="end" parameter to your exp:stash:get tag.

Comment: Perfect. I knew it would be something simple. Thanks.

Comment: Great, went ahead and added it as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stash:get is probably being run in the template parse order before it's value is available. One fix is to have the stash:get run later using process="end" parameter:

```
{exp:stash:get name="child_name" process="end"}
```